# Internet explorer 7 CSS bug

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I am experiencing a CSS issue, sadly it is only encountered in Internet Explorer 7. If you view the web page in IE7 standards you should be able to replicate the issue. You may need to refresh a couple of times until an advert is served that breaks the layout.

The large square adverts are served by a third party that are placed inside `<div class="grid_4 omega">`. The container  for these adverts is `<div class="ad_instance">`

Here is the CSS that has been applied.

```
div.ad_instance {
    clear: right;
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

I have attached a screenshot to demonstrate the issue:

[image]

Any suggestions or amendments to my CSS rules would be much appreciated.

Comment: Cudos for the cookie disclosure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your `clear: right;` definition on class `.ad_instance` is the cause of the bug.

Removing it fixes the issue in IE7, and maintains the same outcome on other browsers (as far as my testing found).